# Referencing an attribute which references a color inside of strings.xml

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm starting to use strings.xml with String.format more often and i was wondering is there anyway to use a reference within a xml string element.

I have the following string:

```
<string name="ticker_media_citation">%1$s by &lt;font color=\'#FF00CC\'> %2$s& lt;/font></string>
```

Using String.format() in conjunction with Html.fromHtml() does the trick. What id like to have is the following:

```
<string name="ticker_media_citation">%1$s by &lt;font color=\'?IndicatorColor\'>%2$s&lt;/font></string>
```

where `?IndicatorColor` references a color.

Unfortunately it doesn't work, so i ask is it even possible or should i just do it the ugly way with Spannables/SpannableStringBuilder?

**Edit -- Further explanation --**

I have an attribute like the following:

```
<declare-styleable name="Theme">
    <attr name="IndicatorColor" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Then i have a theme that uses this refences

```
<style name="Theme.WD.Light" parent="Theme.WD">
    <item name="IndicatorColor">@color/IndicatorColor.Light</item>
</style>
```

And the color

```
<color name="IndicatorColor.Light">#0099CC</color>
```

Id like to be able to reference the color using `?IndicatorColor` and not `@color/IndicaterColor.Light` since the indicator color may change depending on which theme the user has selected.

Answer (score 0):

Look [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html) you can create separate color `resources`. Use the `strings.xml` for `Strings` instead of hard coding text and make use of the other `resources` such as [colors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color) for your different colors.

Comment: This i know, but i cant use a color reference.i need to reference an attribute. Ill edit my post to be a bit more clear.